# How to use Resultset?

Tags: java, mysql

I am using a mysql table, and now I need to compare a columns all values with a given String.

I want to check if all values of the result set matches with `encryptedString`.
Need to understand what result set does and how it works.
Here I have a method, Some variables, and 2 mysql queries.

```
final String secretKey = "!!!!";
String name = jText.getText();
String pass = jTextPass.getText();
String originalString = pass;
String encryptedString = AES.encrypt(originalString, secretKey) ;
String decryptedString = AES.decrypt(encryptedString, secretKey) ;

PreparedStatement PS;
ResultSet result;
String query1 = "SELECT `pass` FROM `Remember_Pass` WHERE `name` =?";

PreparedStatement ps;
String query;
query = "UPDATE `tutor profile` SET `pass`=? WHERE `name`=?";
try {
   PS = MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query1);
   PS.setString(1, name);
   PS.setString(2, encryptedString);
   rs = PS.executeQuery();
   //while(result.next() ){
   //I am not understanding what to do here.
   ps = MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
   ps.setString(1, encryptedString);
   ps.setString(2, name);
   ps.executeUpdate();
   PassSuccess success = new PassSuccess();
   success.setVisible(true);
   success.pack();
   success.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

   this.dispose();
    //}

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ForgetPassT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `ResultSet` object contains all the information about the query that you perform, it will contain all columns. In your code the result variable will return anything since there is no part in your code where is executed, to do this you have to...

```
Statement statement = MyConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("YOUR SELECT STATEMENT HERE");
while(result.next()){
    String column1 = result.getString("columnName");
}
```

The `result.next()` method is a boolean method that says if the `ResultSet` object still have  values of the table inside and it will continue until it reaches the last row that your `SELECT` statement retrives. Now if you want to match the value of some column with other variables you can do it inside the while(result.next()).

`result.getString("columnName")` will extract the value from `columnName` as a `String`.

If you want to save things in an `ArrayList` to save the data and then use this list as you want the code can be like...:

```
Statement statement = MyConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("YOUR SELECT STATEMENT HERE");
List<Object> data = new ArrayList();
while(result.next()){
    data.add(result.getString("columnName"));
}
return data;
```

Obviously you have to change the `Object` with the type of things that you want to store in the List.

Or if you want to store the data in an array. As I said in my comment this won't be dinamic, but...:

```
Statement statement = MyConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("YOUR SELECT STATEMENT HERE");
String[] data = new String[NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS_IN_RESULTSET];
while(result.next()){
    data[0] = result.getString("columnName1");
    data[1] = result.getString("columnName2");
    data[2] = result.getString("columnName3");
    //And so on...
}
return data;
```

The other way is that if you are returning an entity you can set the values of the `ResultSet` directly in the POJO:

```
Statement statement = MyConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("YOUR SELECT STATEMENT HERE");
Entity entity = new Entity();
while(result.next()){
    entity.setColumnName1(result.getString("columnName1"));
    entity.setColumnName2(result.getString("columnName2"));
    entity.setColumnName3(result.getString("columnName3"));
    //And so on...
}
return entity;
```

There are so many ways to store the data, just ask yourself how do you want to receive the data in the other parts of you code.

Regards.

Comment: Sir as I need to save all the values, so then should I use an array instead of column1?

Comment: Sure, the problem here is that it won't be dynamic but you can use an array or even a List, maybe you can use a POJO to save the information, this could be done if you follow the idea that a table in your database is an entity and that an entity is a POJO in you Java code. To do what you say you have to declare the array[0] = result.getString("columnName"); and then array[1] = result.getString("columnName2"); As I said this couldn't be dynamically since the name of the columns could be anything. The same applies to a list: list.add(result.getString("columnName"));

Comment: I have updated my answer in order that you can visualize how you can store and return the data.

Answer (score 0):

First tip: using try-with-resources closes statement and result set even on exception or return. This also reduces the number of variable names for them because of the smaller scopes. This return from the innermost block I utilized. For unique names one can use if-next instead of while-next. A fail-fast by not just logging the exception is indeed also better; you can exchange the checked exception with a runtime exception as below, so it easier on coding.

```
String query1 = "SELECT `pass` FROM `Remember_Pass` WHERE `name` = ?";
String query = "UPDATE `tutor profile` SET `pass`=? WHERE `name`= ?";
try (PreparedStatement selectPS = MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query1)) {}
   selectPS.setString(1, name);
   //selectPS.setString(2, encryptedString);
   try (ResultSet rs = selectPS.executeQuery()) {}
      if (result.next()){ // Assuming `name` is unique.
         String pass = rs.getString(1);
         try (PreparedStatement ps = MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query)) {
            ps.setString(1, encryptedString);
            ps.setString(2, name);
            int updateCount = ps.executeUpdate();
            if (updateCount == 1) {
               PassSuccess success = new PassSuccess();
               success.setVisible(true);
               success.pack();
               success.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
               return success;
            }
         }
      }
   }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ForgetPassT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
} finally {
    dispose();
}
```